# Can I deploy TKinter apps to MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I want to develop a Windows/macOS app on my Windows machine, I aim to upload the executable file and upload it on the internet so that people with macOS can run it just like on windows.
Is that possible?

I tried searching on this topic on the internet and didn't get satisfying results.

Comment: `python` and `tkinter` can work on MacOS/Windows/Linux but if you compile the program into an executable then it becomes platform dependant.

Comment: Wil the app be deployable? or do I have to make a developer account like on iOS?

Comment: if you need to ask then the answer is no, no you can't..

Comment: @toyotaSupra The question is about developing and installing an app that uses `tkinter`, not installing `tkinter` itself.

Comment: You should check out [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) - it allows you to build distributable applications for various platforms (e.g. Mac OS and Windows). The caveat here is that the builds are platform specific. If you're planning to host your app somewhere for download, you'll need to provide both the Mac OS version and the Windows version. Though both versions can be built from the same source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that iOS prohibits installation of apps from unknown sources unless you use your phone for development or jailbreak the phone. So the question was actually if the same is applied to macOS. I know I can build apps and make executable files, one for each platform. I searched the web for a long time until I found the answer, that yes, I can just make a script and run it on macOS without any complications.